# Error with XML file - Android(Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token))

Tags: java, android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-xml

So i got this error and i know its a frequent one but non of the answers on this site have helped me.

XML:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.app.LoginActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <!--  Header Starts-->
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_header_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@layout/header_gradient"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip">

            <!-- Logo Start-->
            <ImageView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/hd_logo"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dip
                />

    </LinearLayout>         
    <!-- Logo Ends -->
    <!--  Header Ends -->

    <!-- Footer Start -->
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_footer_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dip"
        android:background="@layout/footer_repeat"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Footer Ends -->

    <!-- Login Form -->
    <!-- Login Form Ends -->

  </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

So i have got the `Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)` on the closing tag of the LinearLayout `</LinearLayout>`.
Also the closing tag of the `ImageView` `/>` is blue and not green.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot closing double quotation

```
android:layout_marginStart="10dip"
```